# Add array of category IDs to global variable?

Tags: functions, variables

I'm wondering how I can add a global variable containing an array of category IDs.

On my site, I have menus and custom loops and every time I want to delete a category of them, I have to access each and add the ID of the category to be deleted.

My idea is to have a variable with these ids.

```
$excluded = array( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
```

Can I use the `functions.php` for this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution- use GLOBAL variables..

```
$GLOBALS['my_categories_list'] = array(1,2,3,4);
```

then you can everywhere access `$GLOBALS['my_categories_list']`.